# Tutorials on lexicographically first maximal clique?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, reference-request, computer-science

The [lexicographically first maximal clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_a_single_maximal_clique) problem is [P-complete](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Etvrdik/4/html/Section4.html). Could you direct me to any tutorial materials that show how the reduction from [Circuit-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Value_Problem) to lexicographically first maximal clique is done, including worked examples?